# Dropdown list isn't working after importing another html file using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to import `header.html` for avoiding file duplication. But in this situation, I can't use PHP.
This is the head section of `index.html` file,

```
<script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#header").load("header.html");
        $("#footer").load("footer.html");
    });
</script>
```

The body section I have called my `header.html` as follows,

```
<body>
  <!-- include Header -->
  <div id="header"></div>
  <!-- end include header -->
</body>
```

The header is including fine but after the header included the dropdown lists become unclickable. [image: In this image I cant click about us dropdown list]

When I go to inspect elements there are following errors,
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One possible reason for your problem would be that if you already have `<html><head><body>` tags in all header.html, footer.html and your master page. When you import those sub pages in your master page all those tags will come along with contents. If its true delete those tags from your sub pages because your master page should only have one of specific tags

Answer (score 2):

1) Remove the following tags from header.html and footer.html

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

2) Regarding Slick error please make sure you are not calling the init twice, best way would be

```
$('.selector').slick();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get("header.html", function(response){

        $('#header').html(response);

    });

})
```

Comment: this is not php.its jquery

Comment: this script send a request to header.html and get all data of this page and write returned data to #header

Comment: I'll try with this. Thank you @R.tbr

Answer (score -1):

```
  <?php include_once('header.html');?>

    <div id="header"></div>

    <?php include_once('footer.html');?>
```

Comment: I have mentioned that I don't need a suggestion with PHP

Comment: @DebanjanB please read the question again, I have mentioned that I can't work with PHP in this situation.

Comment: @Mr.Semicolon Irrespective of the PHP factor, this answer landed in the VLQ queue. So we have asked the answerer to add the required verbatim.